# Grey box when importing image in html

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to import an image and place it over my background but when I put the image in, its invisible and has a grey box around it. How can I solve this?

HTML CODE -

```
<div id="background">

    <img src"images/twitter.jpg" alt"Twitter Logo" style="width:50px;height:50px"> 


<div id="menu">
    <div class="table">
        <ul id="horizontal-list">
            <li><a href="index.html" class="no-underline" >Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="page2.html" class="no-underline" >All About</a></li>
            <li><a href="page3.html" class="no-underline" >Galley</a></li>
            <li><a href="page4.html" class="no-underline" >Video Clips</a></li>
            <li><a href="page5.html" class="no-underline" >Main Cast</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax error:Just add `=` after `<img src`.
Code :

```
<img src="images/twitter.jpg" alt"Twitter Logo" style="width:50px;height:50px">
```